# php not updating sql database

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

Hello I am running a server side database to process input from an android phone. I have two functions one to store the user information and one to update their location.

The second one to store location I cannot get to work.

```
   /**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

     /**
 * Updating a users
 * location
 */
public function updateLocation($email, $location) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET location='$location' WHERE email='$email' NOW())");

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sanitizing these variables with `mysql_real_escape` before trying to insert them in the database? This is an extremely dangerous way to write code. I strongly suggest you use a database abstraction layer like this instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will certainly look into abstraction layers in future however currently it it out of the scope of this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at your update query `$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET location='$location' WHERE email='$email' NOW())");`  You appear to be missing part of it.  You need to tell it what needs to be set to NOW(), perhaps updated_at,   `"UPDATE users SET location='$location', updated_at = NOW() WHERE email='$email'"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have an error : "`WHERE email='$email' NOW())`" into "`created_at='NOW()' WHERE email='$email'`"

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra  NOW() at the end of your SQL